# Problema con CSS flex wrap (CSS)

Tags: css

Estoy haciendo un formulario en el cual, si no me alcanza en la pantalla deseo que se pase a la siguiente línea:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>titulo</div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>titulo</div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </div>

  <div style="width:100%;">
    <div>titulo</div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>titulo</div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Pero cuando le pongo `width: 100%` al penúltimo, por lógica me ocupa todo el `width` y manda los demás `div` al siguiente renglón, pero yo busco que mis `div` se puedan distribuir al `100%` en el `width` `container`, pero si ya no alcanza pasarse a la siguiente línea con `flex-wrap`.

De antemano, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que cito a continuación:

> Pero cuando le pongo `width` `100%` al penúltimo, por lógica me ocupa todo el `width` y manda los demás `div` al siguiente renglón, pero yo busco que mis `div` se puedan distribuir al `100%` en el `width`...

Debes colocar en los `divs` contenido en `.container` la propiedad `flex-grow` a `1`. Es decir:

```css
.container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Eso hará que se distribuya entre los elementos el ancho disponible, pero también, debes establecer una anchura mínima para lograr ir a la siguiente fila una vez no haya espacio disponible:

```css
.container > div {
  ...
  min-width: 200px; /* Esto es asumiendo que quieres 200px como anchura mínima */
}
```

Para no alargar la explicación dejo el siguiente fragmento con los comentarios:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  /* Propiedad CSS que ayuda distribuir entre los 
     elementos el ancho disponible de su contenedor */
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  /* Esto es, asumiendo que desee 200px de anchura
     mínima */
  min-width: 200px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>Título</div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>Título</div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>Título</div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>Título</div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```